# How to connect BitBucket repository and existing local git project once there is already code on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

**Please note:** although I mention BitBucket here, I think this is a `git` question at heart and can be answered by any experience git user. I only mention BitBucket so that folks are aware that I am **not** using GitHub and as such, *can't* solve the problem with GitHub-specific solutions. But again, I think the answer is 100% on the git command-line.

Also, if given the preference between a BitBucket UI-based solution, or a pure git command-line solution, I certainly prefer the latter!

---

I've got a cart-before-the-horse scenario going on here.

I was asked to create a new project and write some code for it, because at the time the people I'm working with weren't ready for a new repository to be created in their BitBucket workspace. So I got a POC working locally, named my project `some-service` and now am ready to push that project up to a new BitBucket repository to share with other devs. I would like both a main and develop branch (or whatever is the norm for git/BitBucket these days).

Problem is, they are not willing to give me "Create New Repository" permissions, and so they are insisting that *they* create the repository and simply give me read/write access to it. So, on BitBucket, they have created a new repository called `some-service` that contains a `README.md` and a `.gitignore` and it has a sole `master` branch.

Normally on GitHub, I create the repos myself, and they have a `main` branch, and GitHub provides me with a few commad lines to connect/sync up my existing local repo with the new one on GitHub.

What can I do here, ideally solely from the git command line, so that:

- I am able to either clone this repo, or `git init` my local `some-service` project, and "connect them" so that I can `git push` on the command line and push those changes to branches in the remote project on BitBucket; and
- I am able to set the code in my local copy as the `main` branch and push that to BitBucket; and
- Create a `develop` branch in BitBucket and pull that branch down, so that both locally and on BitBucket, I have `main` and `develop`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a remote for your local repository.

Specifically

```
# Add bit bucket repository as remote
git remote add origin <link to bit bucket repository>

# Fetch remote changes (Readme etc)
git fetch origin

# Rebase local commit on top of remote
git rebase origin/master

# Push main branch to origin
git push -u origin main

# GUI interface necessary at this point for BitBucket.
# Navigate to the repository, then enter "Repository settings" (appears on
# the left list menu), enter "ADVANCED", under "Main branch" select 
# "main". Finally, click "Save changes".

# Delete master branch on remote
git push origin --delete master

# Create the develop branch, assuming it doesn't exist
git checkout -b "develop"

# Push develop branch to origin
git push -u origin develop
```

Comment: This is a great answer @zois (+1) -- would you mind giving me _all_ the applicable git command line invocations for this, though? Like when you say "rebase your local changes"? What would I run for that? And how would I make sure the name of the branch is `main`, not `master`, etc.? Ditto for the `develop` commands. Thanks again!